# How to use a template with textboxes loaded with data passed from a calling template in ember.js

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I'm trying to make a addstudent template which can be rendered with data if clicked on editstudent option from another template.

I don't want to make different templates for addStudentDetails and EditstudentDetails. how to create a single template for this both functions.

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you post what youve tried so far?

Comment: You can do it by declaring boolean properties and updating edit field value.

Comment: I've found this video helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QHrlFlaXdI

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple ways of doing this.

1. Handlebar template, using [conditionals](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/conditionals/).
   Then in your controller you can control whether you want to edit or add. 
   The ember guide has a good example of this for [controlling state](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/toggle-todo-editing-state/).
2. Or you can use Routes and Resources. Possibly a Parent Resource called Student and then routes called edit and add. But you said you didn't want to use different templates so I'm assuming you'll probably want to use #1.

```js
//inside your controller
App.StudentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  editStudent: true // or false
});
```

```html
<!-- handlebars template possibly called studentTemplate -->
{{#if editStudent}}
  <!-- code for editStudent -->
{{else}}
  <!-- code for addStudent -->
{{/if}}
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I got a solution for that from this 
**App.js**
     `App.Router.map(function() {
     this.resource('about');
     this.resource('posts', function() {
     this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
     });
     });

    App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
     return posts;
    }
    });

    App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
    return posts.findBy('id', params.post_id);
    }
    });`
**index.html**
`{{#link-to 'post' this}}{{title}}`